# How to show output logs of installed device apps in Visual Studio output?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

Having a Windows Phone device, is it possible the see the output of a installed app into the output of Visual Studio?

Like Android Studio does with logcat.

I guess it's a way to do it with Visual Studio but can't find any info on the web.

Answer (score 0):

Build your app in debug configuration, use [Debug.WriteLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline(v=vs.110).aspx) (.NET) and/or [OutputDebugString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362(v=vs.85).aspx) (C++) function to print messages, launch your app with debugger, and you’ll see the output in visual studio on the Output pane.

If however you want messages from release builds, without USB cable or without Visual Studio, I don’t know built-in ways. When I needed that, I’ve implemented [Syslog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog) UDP client on the phone, and used a freeware [syslog server](http://www.sysrose.com/) to read these messages in real time. Just don't forget to disable that functionality for your marketplace build.